# How can I force a client to call an explicitly specialized template instead of the primary template?

Tags: c++, templates, com

This is pseudocode for what I want to do.

```
template<typename T>
struct ConvertToT
{
    static_assert(false, "Explicit specialization for T required.");

    // Variant will be coerced to this type before calling Convert.
    std::uint32_t GetVariantType()
    {
        return VT_EMPTY;
    }
    T Convert(CComVariant& input)
    {
        return "ERROR!";
    }
};

template<>
struct ConvertToT<std::wstring>
{
    std::uint32_t GetVariantType()
    {
        return VT_BSTR;
    }
    T Convert(CComVariant& input)
    {
        return std::wstring(input.bstrVal, ::SysStringLen(input.bstrVal));
    }
};

/* repeat for several more explicit specializations:
 * template<>
 * struct ConvertToT<...>
 * {
 *     std::uint32_t GetVariantType()
 *     {
 *         return ...;
 *     }
 *     ... Convert(CComVariant& input)
 *     {
 *         return ...;
 *     }
 * };
 */
```

Is there some way I can disable the primary template and require use of an explicit specialization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just don't define the primary template:

```
template <typename> struct ConvertToT;

template <> struct ConvertToT<int>
{
    // ...
};

// etc.
```

If you like a static assertion, you can get compilable code with, you guessed it, one extra level of indirection:

```
template <typename> struct never_true : std::false_type { };

template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    static_assert(never_true<T>::value, "Can't use this.");
};
```

This works for both complete and incomplete types.

(You can also use `!std::is_same<T, T>::value`.)

Comment: +1, and this works. But it doesn't emit a pretty message explaining what happened like `static_assert` does, so holding off on the ✓ for now..

Comment: @BillyONeal: Edited, [here's an example](http://ideone.com/Tuiznb). The key is to make something dependent on the template parameter. I would like to call this technique "dependency injection".

Comment: That's nice. And I can even make `Foo` "`WhileAttemptingConversionTo<T>`" making the message even clearer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is just to not provide an implementation.
Something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct ConvertToT;

template<>
struct ConvertToT<SomeType>
{
    //  ...
};
```

and so on.

Comment: "Implementation" or "definition"? :-)

Comment: Same as Kerrek's answer. Works, but doesn't provide a message explaining what happened. :( +1

Comment: @KerrekSB Same thing, in this case.  But definition does correspond more precisely to the language in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave your initial approach but enhace it with Boost:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_class.html

```
template<typename T>
struct ConvertToT
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(
    (boost::is_class<std::wstring, T>::value),
    "T must be of wstring type"
     );

    // Variant will be coerced to this type before calling Convert.
    std::uint32_t GetVariantType()
    {
        return VT_EMPTY;
    }
    T Convert(CComVariant& input)
    {
    return "ERROR!";
   }
};
```

Or if you are using C++11 use std::is_class.

Comment: If I could define an exact type of the thing, I wouldn't be using templates in the first place :)

Comment: Add to the check more specializations. These pretty prints any mistake done by the user, of course you have to change the check for each new type. I have to admit that is not clean tho.