# Templated implicit type conversion operator

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, casting

I have implemented

```
template<int M, int N, typename T=double>
class matrix{
    // ...
}
```

and would like the ability to use `matrix<1,1,T>` where a `T` is expected.

How should I accomplish this? Would the following work?

```
template<typename T>
operator T(matrix<1, 1, T> mat) {
    return mat(0,0);
}
```

(The reason for even expecting to encounter `matrix<1,1,T>` is that some matrix expressions have that type. For example, multiplying a `matrix<1,3>` by a `matrix<3,1>` evaluates to a `matrix<1,1>`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've listed will not compile, since you're essentially trying to implement a `T` constructor outside the definition of `T`; or if it's a fundamental type, or an array, it makes even less sense.

What you can do instead is implement a casting operator within your matrix class - by either adding it to the general template or specializing `matrix` for M=1 and N=1.

The first option would look like this:

```
template<int M, int N, typename T=double>
class matrix{
    // ...
    operator T() const {
        static_assert(M == 1 and N==1, 
            "Attempting to treat a matrix with multiple cells as a scalar");
        // code to return the single matrix element
    }
}
```

and the second:

```
template<int M, int N, typename T=double>
class matrix{
    // ...
}


template<typename T=double>
class matrix<1, 1, T>{
    // ... some code duplication here with the main template; or maybe
    // actually have different implementation banking on the fact that
    // it's really just a scalar.

    operator T() const {
        // code to return the single matrix element
    }
}
```

but frankly, I don't think I'd recommend any of these options. I'd probably  do one of the following:

- Alter function which takes a T so that it can "naturally" take 1x1 matrices (e.g. by templating)
- Alter function which takes a T so that it can "naturally" take *any* matrix. A lot of scalar work has interesting generalization to matrices.
- Be explicit about the conversion, perhaps writing a `template <typename T> T as_scalar(const matrix<1,1,T> m)` function.

Comment: There are countless functions, including many in the standard library, that take a `double` but not a `matrix<1, 1, double>`. I think this one is a good use of implicit conversion.

Comment: Whenever I try to specialize templates I end up with much duplication. Would the `static_assert` approach accomplish exactly the same as template specialization, because `static_assert` counts as substitution failure in SFINAE?

Comment: How about `operator std::enable_if_t<M==1 && N==1,T>() const {...}`?

Comment: @Museful: About static_assert - I don't think that'll work, since only declartations, not definitions, are considered w.r.t. SFINAE; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16304778/1593077).  The `enable_if_t` sounds like a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the class definition:

```
template<int Md=M, int Nd=N, typename = std::enable_if_t<Md==1 && Nd==1>>
operator T() const {
    return (*this)(0,0);
}
```